# KISSMetrics Node.js Library?

Tags: node.js, analytics, metrics, mixpanel, kissmetrics

Is there a node.js library for the KISSmetrics API (http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/specifications)?

Unfortunately I don't think the client side js (http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/javascript) library works with node.js?

Note: I imagine the node.js library for KISSmetrics would look a lot like the MixPanel library: https://github.com/carlsverre/mixpanel-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just released a node.js library for KISSmetrics. I'm going to use it in production for my own project (wavo.me). Here's the git repo https://github.com/glesperance/node-kissmetrics

Feedback welcome !

Answer (score 7):

Today we released an open source [Node.js library for Segment.io](https://segment.io/libraries/node) that supports sending data to KISSmetrics as well as Mixpanel, Customer.io, Intercom.io and Klaviyo. We also have open source libraries for [Ruby](https://segment.io/libraries/ruby), [Java](https://segment.io/libraries/java), [.NET](https://segment.io/libraries/.net) and [Python](https://segment.io/libraries/python) should you ever need them!

Feedback is always welcome, and we'll be adding more services and language support soon.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it. Install npm. Use npm search text. Check out https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Lastly, the mixpanel client is 150 lines, about half of which are comments. Its very straightforward to create a rest client, especially if they support JSON. https://github.com/carlsverre/mixpanel-node/blob/master/lib/mixpanel-node.js

Generally speaking, client libraries which depend on XHR in the browser don't generally work out of the box. With a baby abstraction and a bit of hacking, you can get most things to work as long as they aren't wholly dependent on the DOM or some other such browser concept. Check out https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest if you're interested in this concept.

Comment: Thanks Josh! Makes sense, will probably point at the KISSMetrics HTTP REST endpoints.